# How to setup .Net Core NUnit testing with Azure Pipelines

Tags: .net-core, nunit, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to setup CI for a library of mine using Azure Pipelines. I've got the .NET Framework tests running but the .NET Core framework targets are throwing the following error.

`System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'nunit.framework' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

It appears this error occurs because of the way .NET Core dependencies are copied as is mentioned in https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/2713#issuecomment-365932475.

My test section of the yml file is as follows.

```
- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    vsTestVersion: '16.0'
```

My question is what should go in an Azure Pipelines yml file for testing with nunit on .NET Core?

Comment: you probably need to restore first?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add task `Visual Studio Test Platform Installer` before the task Visual Studio Test. The task `Visual Studio Test Platform Installer` can be used in a build or release pipeline to acquire the Microsoft test platform from nuget.org or a specified feed, and add it to the tools cache, and it satisfies the ‘vstest’ demand and can be used for running tests and collecting diagnostic data using the Visual Studio Test task.

[image: Visual Studio Test Platform Installer]

Comment: @TylerBrinkley, can you find the file nunit.framework in the repo? When published the test project, this file will be in the publish target directory.And can you confirm the `Search Folder` parameter of the vstest task is available?Please provide more debug info.